# C# HttpListener not connecting to localhost

Tags: c#, http, networking

I want to make some server using `HttpListener` but whenever I send a request to it using a browser tab, that request takes infinite time to reach the server.

1. Tried netsh to give permission to use sockets. Didn't work. `netsh http show urlacl` output is below:

```
    Reserved URL            : http://localhost:12113/
        User: \Everyone
            Listen: Yes
            Delegate: No
            SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;WD)

    Reserved URL            : http://127.0.0.1:12113/
        User: \Everyone
            Listen: Yes
            Delegate: No
            SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;WD)

    Reserved URL            : http://+:12113/
        User: \Everyone
            Listen: Yes
            Delegate: No
            SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;WD)

    Reserved URL            : http://*:12113/
        User: \Everyone
            Listen: Yes
            Delegate: No
            SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;WD)
```

2. Firewall is not blocking my port. Still not working.
3. Some said running VS in admin privileges might work. But it didn't.
4. If I try connecting with the server closed (or to another port that is not listened), browser will return `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. But when I do it with the server open, it just never responds. No errors, no successes.

Server code is as follows:

```
public class Server
{
    public static HttpListener Listener;
    public static int Port = 12113;

    public Server()
    {
        Listener = new HttpListener();
        
        // Yeah, I got so mad I added them all (same as urlacl)
        Listener.Prefixes.Add($"http://localhost:{Port}/");
        Listener.Prefixes.Add($"http://127.0.0.1:{Port}/");
        Listener.Prefixes.Add($"http://+:{Port}/");
        Listener.Prefixes.Add($"http://*:{Port}/");
        
        Listener.Start();

        var listenTask = HandleIncomingConnections();
        listenTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        Listener.Stop();
    }

    public async Task HandleIncomingConnections()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var context = await Listener.GetContextAsync();

            var request = context.Request;
            var response = context.Response;
            var user = context.User;

            await HandleRequest(request, response, user);
        }
    }
    private async Task HandleRequest(HttpListenerRequest request, HttpListenerResponse response, IPrincipal user)
    {
        // There's a breakpoint right here so that I can inspect what I received
        // and develop the server accordingly, but it is never hit.
    }

    public void Shutdown()
    {
        try
        {
            Listener.Stop();
        }
        catch
        {
            // ignore
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you have no deadlock here? You blocked thread on `GetResult()` then trying to do something async in the `HandleIncomingConnections` at the same time.

Comment: You're starting to listen in your `Server` constructor. So the constructor will never return. Try to Start your server in an async method, so you don't have to call `GetResult`, that can cause deadlocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Jesse de Wit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3883866/jesse-de-wit) and [Serg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2011071/serg) said, it was in a deadlock. I got it working like this:

```
public Server()
{
    Listener = new HttpListener();
    Listener.Prefixes.Add($"http://localhost:{Port}/");
    Listener.Prefixes.Add($"http://127.0.0.1:{Port}/");
    Listener.Prefixes.Add($"http://+:{Port}/");
    Listener.Prefixes.Add($"http://*:{Port}/");
    Start();
}

public async void Start()
{
    Listener.Start();
    await HandleIncomingConnections();
    Stop();
}
```

What I've been struggling for a whole week was just my mistake. Thanks guys.